# Creating character image

Tags: c#, c, image, swift, char

I'd like to create database for a project with images from different characters (using many different fonts), but could find any resource about that on the net. How can I do that? I know the following languages: C, C#, Objective-C/Swift. So, any proposition with them is fine. I may also consider languages similar to them.

Comment: I'm afraid that this question as written is wildly off topic for StackOverflow.  If you can narrow it down to a specific implementation and tag it as such then perhaps you'd get a few ideas.  It is far too broad currently however.

Comment: There are couple questions on "how to render text into bitmap/image" for all imaginable language/framework combinations. I.e. I've marked this as duplicate of answer for C#/`System.Drawing`.